# JDBC and updatable ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, updates, resultset

I'm learning a little bit about JDBC and how to interact with databases. I get the basics but have now run into a problem with updatable resultsets. In this excercise I have to check the stock of every beer in the database and add 50 to it.

So this little piece of code does work, but not all the time. i've run it several times and about 50% of the time the stock has actually gone up. to check this I've written another small while loop that prints a table with the necessary data. any ideas why it doesnt work a 100% of the time?

the database has 1071 records in there and I've been running this code immediately after getting the results. Should I wait before running it again?

```
package stockbier;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class bierenstock {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://noelvaes.eu/StudentDB", "student", "student123");
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement
        ("select * from Beers", 
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);) {

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
            // edited int stock
        int stock = rs.getInt("Stock") + 50;
        rs.updateInt("Stock", stock);
        rs.updateRow();

    }

    rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://noelvaes.eu/StudentDB", "student", "student123");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement
    ("select * from Beers", 
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);) {

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    int stock = rs.getInt("Stock") + 50;
    rs.updateInt("Stock", stock);
    rs.updateRow();
}

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}    
}
```

The type of a ResultSet object determines the level of its functionality in two areas: the ways in which the cursor can be manipulated, and *how concurrent changes made to the underlying data source are reflected by the ResultSet object.*

**TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE**:

> The result can be scrolled; its cursor can move both forward and
>   backward relative to the current position, and it can move to an
>   absolute position. The result set is insensitive to changes made to
>   the underlying data source while it is open. It contains the rows that
>   satisfy the query at either the time the query is executed or as the
>   rows are retrieved.

**TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE**:

> The result can be scrolled; its cursor can move both forward and
>   backward relative to the current position, and it can move to an
>   absolute position. The result set reflects changes made to the
>   underlying data source while the result set remains open.

Refer [Updating ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_update) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Does your table have PRIMARY KEY?

> Specifying that a result set be updatable does not guarantee that the
>   result set you get will actually be updatable. Drivers that do not
>   support updatable result sets will return one that is read-only. In
>   addition, to get an updatable result set, the query must generally
>   specify the primary key as one of the columns selected, and it should
>   select columns from only one table.

Comment: thanks for commenting Marius, but it has been a while since i was writing that code and I cant possibly remember anymore. basically i havent touched JDBC after completing this excercise! I'm working on a project now where we use exclusively hibernate.

Comment: Np. Super that you are working on a project now! I am reading a book "Java Database Programming Bible" on JDBC. It has examples and is simple. :)